# "I would have met you on Monday, but I will be out of the country"

Tags: present-perfect, would, will-would

I have an argument with a couple of friends about the following situation:

I want to meet someone on Monday, in the future, but I can't because I will be out of the country. So I told him:

> I would have met you on Monday, but I will be out of the country.

A few friends said it is wrong, and should be something like:

> I would meet you on Monday, but I will be out of the country.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Your version emphasises the (projected) meeting itself while your friend's version emphasises the willingness to meet.

Answer (score 1):

They're both correct. The first uses what's known as a doubly remote conditional.

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English* *Language* p754,

> The doubly remote conditional construction
>
> i *If you had told me you were busy I would **have** come tomorrow.*
>
> ii *If you **had** come tomorrow you would **have** seen the carnival.*
>
> iii *If your father **had** been alive today he would **have** been
> distraught to see his business disintegrating like this.*
>
> Ordinary remote conditionals have preterite tenses (or irrealis mood)
> expressing modal remoteness, not past time. In [48] the underlined
> perfect auxiliaries ***have*** also express modal rather than temporal
> meaning. In [i] the apodosis situation is future; in [ii] both
> protasis and apodosis situations are future; and in [iii] both
> situations are located in present time.We refer to this, therefore, as
> the **doubly remote conditional**: the remoteness is signalled twice,
> once by the preterite inflection, once by perfect ***have***.
>
> Where the time is future the doubly remote construction indicates not
> only that *P* and *Q* are false, but also that the possibility of the
> future situation being actualised has already been foreclosed by a
> past event. In [i–ii], for example, it might be that I or you have
> come today, with the assumption that that precludes our coming again
> tomorrow.

If the protasis (conditional adjunct) were present, the doubly-remote version would require a ***have*** in the protasis as well. The other would exclude it.

> (If I **could have** met you on Monday), I **would have** met you on Monday, but I will
> be out of the country.
>
> (If I **could** meet you on Monday), I **would** meet you on Monday, but I will be out of
> the country.

Answer (score 0):

Fanchette, at [Word Reference_Forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/i-would-have-come-with-you-tomorrow-if-i-hadnt-already-promised-mixed-conditionals-future-past.2526135/), states:

> In 'Grammar in context' by Hugh Gethin I found the information:
> 'Sometimes the conditional or past tense is 'shifted back' to the
> conditional perfect or past perfect to give a sentence with uniform
> tense use:
>
> - *I would have come with you tomorrow if I hadn't already promised...*
>
> ...

[Is this really grammatical? What does 'sometimes' imply?]

To which Cagey responds:

> It's difficult to answer your question, because [this sentence is not
> a construction] I would use, though I can understand what [it is]
> supposed to mean.
>
> Instead of
>
> - *I would have come with you tomorrow if I hadn't already promised...*
>
> if I were turning down an invitation, I might say:
>
> - *I would come with you tomorrow if I hadn't already promised.*...

I'll add that I find the initial sentence unremarkable, quite acceptable.

Comment: O.K., so what is the answer? Two people happen to disagree, without offering arguments for their respective positions, and there is nothing more to say?

Comment: Hugh Gethin has written various books on grammar, and he makes a statement I agree with. A contributor to an English website doesn't. I'm claiming that this is one of the grey areas Svartvik and Greenwald said must be considered to exist, where opinion is divided over acceptability.

Comment: **Why** do you agree with him? If you have an **argument** as to why his view is more convincing than the opposite one, it would be a worthwhile contribution to this site to make it known what that argument is.

Comment: DW256 gives a rather more highly esteemed reference (CGEL) which maintains that both alternatives are correct. So 'It is true that 'I would have met you on Monday' is incorrect according to the standard textbook rules if Monday is in the future' is what is incorrect.

Comment: **(1)** CGEL is a monograph presenting the theories of its particular authors; it is hardly a textbook. **(2)** It is, of course, true that the correct form of a conditional is ultimately a matter of modalities, rather than time, but time is a good proxy for modalities in so far as the past is unchangeable. As the quotation from CGEL in DW256's answer itself says, in these cases 'the possibility of the future situation being actualised has already been foreclosed by a **past** event'. In the OP's case, the possibility of meeting on Monday was foreclosed by a past decision.

Comment: I don't think I've seen such inventive use of spin for a long time. I'm sure that few on ELU would argue that CGEL doen-t usually outrank the standard school textbooks, whether we argue it sits alongside textbooks or hovercraft.

Comment: Nobody said anything about outranking until the preceding comment. Huddleston and Pullum's book outranks the standard textbooks in sophistication, complexity, etc., but that itself implies that it is not a standard textbook. Maybe we have a misunderstanding as to the meaning of the word *textbook*.

Comment: 'Textbook' or 'Monograph' is neither here nor there: it's how reliable these works are judged to be by linguists.

Comment: I was responding your criticism of my claim that "'It is true that 'I would have met you on Monday' is incorrect according to the standard textbook rules if Monday is in the future'". That claim was about textbooks, i.e. books used in teaching that often simplify the truth for their didactic purposes. In fact, if you actually read (2) in my earlier comment, you will see that I essentially agree with what CGEL says on this particular topic, and that my answer is consistent with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that 'I would have met you on Monday' is incorrect according to the standard textbook rules if Monday is in the future, because 'would have met' is, according to these rules, to be used only for the past. Nevertheless, if one doesn't think about the rules, the wording does not strike one as incorrect. Why?

The explanation is that even though 'I would have met you on Monday' is, on its face, about the future, it is implicitly about the past decision whether to meet the person on Monday. One can thus interpret 'I would have met you on Monday' as an abbreviation of something like 'I would have decided yesterday to meet you on Monday'. When the sentence is interpreted that way, the use of 'would have' in it ceases to be problematic.

Comment: If we start allowing all sorts of possible deletions we're into the realms of crossword clues, not verifiable issues or issues which can be shown to have divided usage.

Comment: 'incorrect according to the standard textbook rules' needs supporting references on ELU. CGEL is a textbook ('
a book used as a standard work for the study of a particular subject': [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/textbook). And [Gethin's](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2831797-grammar-in-context) reviews are at least reasonable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, this is becoming unproductive. I don't think that this exchange is going to benefit any of the future visitors to this page. In the interest of helping these visitors by making the page less cluttered, I will delete all my comments on this page, if you delete all of yours. The answers can then speak for themselves.

Answer (score -1):

'I would have met you' indicates the past, not the future. So the first sentence is not correct.

Past- could have + past participle, should have + past participle, must have + past participle, *would have + past participle*

'Would' is used for a past prediction. He worked all day. He would sleep well.

We can say 'I would like to meet you on Monday, but I will be out of the country.'